# How to access a DataContext, that has been specified in XAML, from within code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm specifying my `DataContext` view model inside my XAML, as follows:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:SeasonDivisionViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

If that `SeasonDivisionViewModel` class has a public property, is it possible to access this from within the code-behind?

I'm trying to learn and take one step at a time, and I'd like to avoid adding commands yet, and just populate data from within code-behind, for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to access the DataContext after the view loads on the code behind you can simply use this.

```
var viewModel = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
```

Where MyViewModel is the data type of your data context.

Comment: You can also access it in the DataContextChanged event.